# Django Rest Framework associating Related Model with current User

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'll start by explaining the current scenario of my problem.

## Models

There are 5 models for example: `Community`, `User`, `Membership`, `Reservation`, `Item`

```
class User(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    communities = ManyToManyField('Community', through='Membership')


class Community(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)


class Membership(Model):
    user = ForeignKey('User')
    community = ForeignKey('Community')


class Item(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)


class Reservation(Model):
    item = ForeignKey('Item')
    membership = ForeignKey('Membership')
```

> - `Community` is m:m `User` through `Membership`.
> - `Reservation` is 1:m `Membership`
> - `Item` is 1:m `Reservation`

## ModelSerializer

```
class ReservationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('membership', 'item')
```

## Problem

What's the best approach to automatically set the `User` value from `request.user`, hence the attribute that is required for this `ReservationSerializer` is just the `community` and `item` instead of `membership` and `item`?

## References

- [How to create a django User using DRF's ModelSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19769186/764592)
- [Return the current user with Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15770488/764592)
- http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions#associating-snippets-with-users
- [Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer Set attribute on create](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23216280/764592)
- [Dynamically limiting queryset of related field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15328632/764592)
- [djangorestframework: Filtering in a related field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18625805/764592)

Comment: I am trying to leverage the ModelSerializer, as much as I could, so that I can avoid writing custom serializer from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The role of the serializer is to represent the information in a legible way, not to manipulate such data. You may want to do that on a view: Using the generic ListCreateAPIView available on DRF, you could use the `pre_save` signal to store that information:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView

class ReservationView(ListCreateAPIView):
    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.membership.user = self.request.user
```

Comment: The issues is that the client has to make a GET request on the Membership resource, just to get the `membership_id` before able to POST to the `Reservation` resource, which I think an extra step that is not necessarily to be done on every client. They should be able to do POST with their current `community_id`, without having to know what is the membership_id for my own account in this community.

Comment: in DRF 3.x this was renamed to perform_create() http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users